# List all application URLs on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there a way to list all the application url schemes registered on a device?
(also on a jailbroken device)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the list [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). I don't know haw you can list all the url schemes for the app on the device.